# Обнулить setInterval в функции

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется слайдер новостей, новости там меняются каждые 5 секунд автоматически. Также есть возможность сменить новость вручную по нажатию на кнопку

```js
 function display_block(id){
   $('.paging .active').removeClass("active");
   $('#button-'+id).addClass("active");

   $('.other-top-news .single-news ').css('display','none');
   $('.news-'+id).css('display','block');
  }

  function NewsRotator () {
   {/literal}
   var count_news = {$list|@count};
   {literal}
   for(var i=0; i<count_news; i++){
    if($('.news-'+i).is(':visible'))
    {
     $('.news-'+i).css('display','none');
     $('#button-'+i).removeClass("active");
     if(i < (count_news-1)){
      var j = i+1;
      $('.news-'+j).css('display','block');
      $('#button-'+j).addClass("active");
     }
     else{
      $('.news-0').css('display','block');
      $('#button-0').addClass("active");
     }
     break;
    }
    
   }
  }
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var I = setInterval(NewsRotator, 5000);
   });
```

```html
<div class="other-top-news" id="news-1">
              <p>текст</p>
 </div><!-- other-top-news-text -->
<div class="other-top-news" id="news-2">
              <p>текст</p>
 </div><!-- other-top-news-text -->
<div class="other-top-news" id="news-3">
              <p>текст</p>
 </div><!-- other-top-news-text -->
    <div class="paging">
        <a href="" id="button-1" class="active" onclick="display_block(1);return false;"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a>
       <a href="" id="button-2" class="active" onclick="display_block(2);return false;"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a>
       <a href="" id="button-3" class="active" onclick="display_block(3);return false;"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a>
    </div> <!-- paging -->
```

на html не обращайте внимание, он сокращен, все функции прекрасно работают. Вопрос в том как обнулить `setInterval` при нажатии на ссылку, по которой вызывается `display_block`? `setInterval` вызывается глобально, и как передать эту переменную в локальную функцию для `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте переменную таймера в window-объект:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.timer = setInterval(NewsRotator, 5000);
})
function display_block(id){
    clearInterval(window.timer);
    $('.paging .active').removeClass("active");
    ('#button-'+id).addClass("active");

    $('.other-top-news .single-news ').css('display','none');
    $('.news-'+id).css('display','block');
}
```

Comment: Объявлять переменную в глобальной области видимости кто будет?

Comment: @Visman, извините, не то вставил:). Обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, а у меня что то с глобальной не получилось в первый раз... И тогда еще вопрос, чтобы снова он заработал, нужно вызвать setInterval(NewsRotator, 5000) после clear?

Comment: Вынесите в отдельную функцию пуск таймера и вызыывайте ее

Comment: а можно как то проследить время таймера в консоли?

Comment: @Vadim.K http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144711/javascript-find-the-time-left-in-a-settimeout